# ¿Cómo puedo separar un tipo enum?

Tags: c#, enum

tengo el siguiente tipo enumerado:

```
using System;

namespace Music
{
 [Flags]
    public enum Days
    {
        None = 0,
        Mon = 1,
        Tue = 2,
        Wed = 4,
        Thu = 8,
        Fri = 16,
        Sat = 32,
        Sun = 64

    }
 }
```

Quiero que, en dos variables de Days, por ejemplo:

```
Days myDays1 = Days.Mon | Days.Thu | Days.Fri | Days.Sat;
Days myDays2 = Days.Mon | Days.Tue | Days.Sat;
```

Usando `myDays1 & myDays2` quiero obtener los días que coinciden pero por separado para poder comprobar otras cosas, o sea, quiero tener `Days.Mon` por una parte i `Days.Sat` por otra. ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Imagino que esas variables son de tipo List o Array no?

Comment: Como dice Pablo, una colección podría contener esos datos, y tu poder guardar los enums que mencionas en ellos. Intentalo a ver como te sale ;)